# nthchild nested problem property that just apply on the firt element

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem with the nth-child proprety.

The problem is on `#subnav` element. I don't understand why nth-child doesn't work (suppose to change border color and width).

Here my problem and code :

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- subnav -->
<ul id="subnav">
      <li><a href=""><span>Philosophie</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>Musiciens</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>Programmes</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>Médias</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>Agenda</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the sass

```css
.container {
    #subnav {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        li {
            padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            border-bottom: 4px 0.5rem;
            border-color: solid #f36e52;
        }
        a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            span:nth-child(1):after, span:nth-child(2):after{
                content: '';
                height: 4px;
                text-align: right;
                float:right;
                margin-top: 0.3rem;
            }
            span:nth-child(1):after {
                width: 30%;
                background-color: #f36e52;
                
           }
            span:nth-child(2):after {
                content: '';
                width: 100%!important;
                background-color: #fff555;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to change the width and also the color of each links, but it only take the attributes of `span:nth-child(1)`.

Any idea ? thanks for your help

Comment: Please make provide more details about what you want to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

They all spans are first-child (or nth-child(1)), you should use `nth-child` on `li` to select correctly.

And to change the color of links you should write `color` attribute directly on `span` not :after.

The final code should be like below:

```
#subnav {
    li {
        &:nth-child(1) {
            span {
                color: red;
            
                &:after {
                    content: '';
                    /*some code*/
                }
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
            span {
                color: green;
            
                &:after {
                    content: '';
                    /*some code*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```